# Using stdout as an argument in for loop

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh, gnu

How can I use the stdout of the echo command as an argument in a for loop.

```
echo NUMBER | for i in {1..$NUMBER}; do if [ $(( $i % 2 )) -eq 0 ]; then echo "even"; fi; done
```

In this example, I wish to loop over a sequence of numbers with a length equal to the integer outputted by echo. How can I do this in a single command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list for a `for` loop cannot read from standard input. However, you can't combine brace expansion and parameter expansion like this in the first place (a common mistake).

Use a C-style for loop instead, setting the value of `NUMBER` however you like prior to the loop.

```
read NUMBER  # reads from standard input
for ((i=1; i <= $NUMBER; i++)); do
    ...
done
```

This also lets you skip the repeated division in your original question. Instead of *filtering* the even numbers from the full range, just generate *only* the even numbers.

```
for ((i=2; i <= $NUMBER; i+= 2)); do
    echo even
done
```

Comment: This works, but I would like it to fit on a single line (executable from command line).

Comment: Write `read NUMBER; for ((...); do ...; done` if you like. The newlines aren't particularly significant. Semicolons serve the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @chepner, the `for` loop alone can't accomplish what you're trying to do. One work around is to use  the `read` builtin to save/capture the input and the `{}` braces for command grouping. Something like.

```
echo 10 | { read -r input; for ((i=1; i<=input; i++)); do ((i%2==0)) && printf '%d is even\n' "$i"; done;  }
```

---

You could also do things like:

```
{ read -r input; for ((i=1; i<=input; i++)); do ((i%2==0)) && printf '%d is even\n' "$i"; done; } < <(echo 10)
```

and:

```
{ read -r input; for ((i=1; i<=input; i++)); do ((i%2==0)) && printf '%d is even\n' "$i"; done;  } <<< 10
```

Output

```
2 is even
4 is even
6 is even
8 is even
10 is even
```